# Why isn't the UIButton I'm using for a UIBarButtonItem changing in height?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

I'm creating a button and adding it as a `UIBarButtonItem` in the code below. I'm trying to make it a perfect circle.

```
UIButton *hasMessageBtn = [UIButton alloc];
hasMessageBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
hasMessageBtn.layer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 24, 24);
hasMessageBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 12;

[hasMessageBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(openMessages:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *messages = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:hasMessageBtn];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = messages;
```

[image]

It looks like the size is wrong in two ways, though. The height never changes, and even thought the width changes when I change the width value, it seems to be incorrect because setting corner radius,

```
hasMessageBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 12;
```

doesn't completely close the rounded corners on the top and bottom. What am I missing here?

Comment: try to set breakpoint and check size of your button. I was copying your code and use it for UIView, and it's transformed to the circle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When you takes smaller the default size of custom view, its height will stretch the height to `34`. That's why your `leftBarButton` getting distorted.

**Solution:**

1. Apply height and width constraint to `barButton` **(Suggested *)**

   ```
   UIBarButtonItem *messages = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:hasMessageBtn];

   [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[[messages.customView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:24.0], [messages.customView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:24.0]]];
   ```
2. Make your custom view's button size, `CGSize(34, 34)`

   ```
   hasMessageBtn.layer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 34, 34);

   hasMessageBtn.layer.cornerRadius = hasMessageBtn.frame.size.height / 2;
   ```

Answer (score 1):

As of iOS 11 you must set constraints to bar button items. Here is how it looks in objective-c:

```
[hasMessageBtn.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:24].active = YES;
[hasMessageBtn.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:24].active = YES;
```

And in swift:

```
hasMessageBtn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24).isActive = true
hasMessageBtn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24).isActive = true
```

If you have more inquiries about this topic I suggest you to look at 2017 WWDC video [Updating Your App for iOS 11](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/204)